# "Missing essential plugins: Pythonid" after installing PyCharm professional 2019.3

Tags: windows, pycharm

After installing 2019.3 on Windows as an upgrade from 2019.2, I am greeted with this message:

[image]

I reinstalled PyCharm from scratch, and am still hitting the same error. Any idea what could have gone wrong and how to fix it?

*(As a work-around, uninstalling 2019.3 and reinstalling 2019.2.5 works.)*

Comment: We stopped using PyCharm Professional. Visual Studio Code works perfectly for us.

Comment: That said, the Jetbrains support is OK, open a ticket there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is caused by the disabled YAML plugin. See the relevant ticket in the PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38866. Basically you need to re-enable the plugin.

Remove `org.jetbrains.plugins.yaml` from

- macOS: `~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2019.3/disabled_plugins.txt`
- Ubuntu: `~/.PyCharm2019.3/config/disabled_plugins.txt`
- Windows: `C:\Users\<USER>\.PyCharm2019.3\config\disabled_plugins.txt`

Comment: For me. the file was located here:
C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2023.2
Hope it helps someone!