# PyCharm Installation

Tags: python, installation, pycharm

I installed PyCharm Community (version - 2021.1) on Windows machine and was able to launch it successfully. However, I was trying to install a few plugins unfortunately i do not remember which all. After the installation, it asked me to restart the PyCharm which I did, and after that, everytime i launch the PyCharm, I keep getting the message

> Missing Essential Plugin :
> com.jetbrains.pycharm.community.customization.
> Please reinstall PyCharm from scratch

I did re-installed the application, but I am still receiving the same error message.
Can someone please guide what needs to be done to use PyCharm again ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this workaround for now, for your version and let me know, if it works or not.

["Missing essential plugins: Pythonid" after installing PyCharm professional 2019.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309628/missing-essential-plugins-pythonid-after-installing-pycharm-professional-2019)

Comment: It seems that, the version 2021.1 of PyCharm still has the problem and the mentioned folder structure is also not visible . the last comment on the same thread, highlights the issue with the mentioned version

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\.Pycharm.X\config\disabled_plugins.txt
```

Try deleting this file inside this given path.

Comment: I am not able to find this folder structure .. After reaching the level -> C:\Users\<Username>\ , i am not able to find any folder with name ".PyCharm*". Also tried by displaying the hidden files

Comment: It seems that, the version 2021.1 of PyCharm still has the problem and the mentioned folder structure is also not visible

Comment: C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming Try this path , you might get the folder and the look for disabled_plugin.txt